# CSS images overlaps in while loop

Tags: html, css

i have following HTML code:

(this code creates box with image, product title and basic description)

```
<?php
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($q3)) {
    echo "<div class='ipsBox_containerdlc ipsPad'>
<h3 class='ipsType_subtitledlc'>".$row[2]." </h3>
<br>
<p class='descdlc'>".$row[4]."</p>
<p class='descdlcimg'>
<img src='http://localhost/images/249273625.jpg' width='200' height='219'/>
</p></div>
";
  }
?>
```

and CSS code:

```
.descdlc {
font-size: 12px;
color: #777777;
    position:relative;
    left:375px;
    width:375px;
}

.descdlcimg {
font-size: 12px;
color: #777777;
    position:relative;
    top:-143px;
    left:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.ipsBox_containerdlc {
    background: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #CECED1;
    border-right: 1px solid #CECED1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CECED1;
    border-top: 1px solid #CECED1;
            height:240px;
    }
```

Problem is that my images "overlaps" if i use  while loop:

Any ideas how to fix it?
Without while loop everything looks fine!

Update:

Comment: `top:-143px;` For every image will surely melt them together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you position the `.descdlcimg` [relative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) with `top: -143px`. This means

> "position this image 143px higher than where it should be."

I think your image "melts" just these 143px to the top. If you don't have a good reason for this relative positioning (heads up: often people say `position: relative` when they mean `position: absolute`) just remove it and it should work.

Comment: Thank you sir, i changed that but images still overlaps.

Comment: Maybe and an margin-bottom.

Comment: I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U9gtZ/1/) from the code you provided. For me it works (images are positioned higher but not overlapping). Please change it if I made anything wrong (I assume the php code produces what I made here). Is there other code that affects your image? (Check this with your browsers developer tools - right-click > inspect element > css)

Comment: Looks like ipsBox_containerdlc messed it up:  I removed height and now they doesnt overlaps Now it looks like this   [link](http://s23.postimg.org/60tif9p17/Untitled.png) how i can fix that? Thank you ALOT!

Comment: Your link is blocked by my workspace virus scanner, he yells "Mal/HTMLGen-A found!". What is wrong there?

Comment: i changed position:relative; to position:absolute in descdlc and now it works like a charm. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try to be consistent and tidy with your indentation, will make code much easier to read and easier to find errors.

I'm not sure but are class names (and ID names for that matter) in CSS/HTML allowed to have spaces in?

Try putting `float: left;` in `.descdlcimg`.